# findModuleByPath("host") returns nullptr in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, omnet++

In OMNeT++ I'm working on example aloha. I try adding acknowledge message sent from server to the node. So, I have defined `cModule *host` and added `host = findModuleByPath("host");` line to the `initialize()` method in Server.cc but it returns nullptr and I have seen the getModuleByPath() method also does the same work but throws and exception instead of returning a nullptr.

It cannot find the host module even though I have defined it. I believe I am missing something but I don't know what. Is there a good example of network (with multiple nodes) that also sends acknowledgement message?

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in using  `cModule *host = findModuleByPath("host")` in `initialize()` of server.

1. According to [4.11.4 Finding Modules by Path](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:finding-modules-by-path) that command leads to looking for a submodule named `host` inside the current module, i.e. in server. Of course, server does not contain host, so it results in returning `nullptr`. To find a sibling module called `host` one should use
   `cModule *host = findModuleByPath("^.host")`.
2. In Aloha there is no single `host` module, but a vector of modules. It means, that first host has the name `host[0]`, the second - `host[1]` etc. Therefore, it would be possible to use:
   `cModule *host = findModuleByPath("^.host[2]")`
   Another way is the following command:
   `cModule *host = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("host", 2)`
3. Be aware that `initialize()` is called sequentially in modules in the network and the order of choosing the next module is not guaranteed by the simulation environment, e.g. `initialize()` was called in `host[1]` but not yet in `server`.
   [Multi-Stage Initialization](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:multi-stage-init) may be used to be sure that one stage of `initialize()` has been performed in all modules.

Comment: Thank you it helped but I am trying to send a message to host and seems like host does not have an "in" gate and server seems to not have "out" gate similarly. I'm trying to add but since they are not connected it doesn't work and I get " 'Aloha.server.out' is not connected to sibling or parent module." error.

Comment: Take note, that Aloha uses radio transmission and there is no wired connections between modules. Messages in a radio system are sending using [Direct Message Sending](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:direct-sending).